# Dependency parse large text file with python

Tags: parsing, dependencies, stanford-nlp

I am trying to parse a large txt file (about 2000 sentence). when I want to set the model_path, I get this massage:

NLTK was unable to find stanford-parser.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
  environment variable.
And also when I set the CLASSPATH to this file, another message comes out:
NLTK was unable to find stanford-parser-(\d+)(.(\d+))+-models.jar!
  Set the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Would you help me to solve it?
This is my code:

> > > import nltk
> > >
> > > from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser
> > >
> > > dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(  model_path="edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz")

===========================================================================
  NLTK was unable to find stanford-parser.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
  environment variable.

For more information, on stanford-parser.jar, see:

## https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

> > > import os
> > >
> > > os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05/*"
> > >
> > > dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser(  model_path="edu\stanford\lp\models\lexparser\englishPCFG.ser.gz")

===========================================================================
  NLTK was unable to find stanford-parser.jar! Set the CLASSPATH
  environment variable.

For more information, on stanford-parser.jar, see:

## https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

> > > os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05/stanford-parser-full-2018-10-17/stanford-parser.jar"

## >>> dependency_parser = StanfordDependencyParser( model_path="stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05/stanford-parser-full-2018-10-17/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")

NLTK was unable to find stanford-parser-(\d+)(.(\d+))+-models.jar!
  Set the CLASSPATH environment variable.

For more information, on stanford-parser-(\d+)(.(\d+))+-models.jar, see:
    https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You should get the new `stanfordnlp` dependency parser that is native to Python!
It will run slower on the CPU than GPU, but it still should run reasonably fast.

Just run `pip install stanfordnlp` to install.

```
import stanfordnlp
stanfordnlp.download('en')   # This downloads the English models for the neural pipeline
nlp = stanfordnlp.Pipeline() # This sets up a default neural pipeline in English
doc = nlp("Barack Obama was born in Hawaii.  He was elected president in 2008.")
doc.sentences[0].print_dependencies()
```

There is also a helpful command line tool:

```
python -m stanfordnlp.run_pipeline -l en example.txt
```

Full details here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/

GitHub: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/stanfordnlp